# Accessing a WMS layer from geoserver and adding it in cesium globe

Tags: geoserver, wms, cesium

I had tried adding a WMS layer from geoserver to cesium globes by below code

```
var widget = new Cesium.CesiumWidget('cesiumContainer');
var url='http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms'; //Geoserver URL
var layers = widget.scene.globe.imageryLayers;
layers.removeAll();
layers.addImageryProvider(new Cesium.WebMapServiceImageryProvider({
    url : url,        
    layers: 'Vishakapatnam:Vishakapatnam_Imagery'
}));
```

The WMS layer is not getting added in the globe. Even i tried adding cors filter in /etc/tomcat7/web.xml. But no luck.

Comment: does the request show up in the geoserver log?

Comment: Where should  i find logs? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: either look in the logs directory of your geoserver data directory, or in the second menu on the left of the GeoServer home page (GeoServer Logs).

Comment: I had pasted the entire logs here http://pastebin.com/HVWSFyjV

Comment: We just need to see if the request shows up and only you know when you made a request

Comment: Well. I did seeing using the firebug and i dont see any request to geoserver.